# Location Proxy with npm serve

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, proxy, serve

If I'm serving a react application with `npm install -g serve; serve -s build`, is it possible to also have a location proxy?

Ex: any requests to `https://example.com/api/*` will be redirected to `https://example.com:8000/api/*`

Comment: Tracking such request here - https://github.com/vercel/serve-handler/issues/30

Answer (score 1):

You can try proxy in package.json

```
"proxy": {
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3001"
    },
    "/assets": {
      "target": "http://localhost:3001"
    }
  },
```

You may also check environment config options here if above does not solve: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#proxy

Answer (score 1):

As commented by [sai anudeep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50166286/location-proxy-with-npm-serve#comment116630989_50166286), there is an [open ticket](https://github.com/vercel/serve-handler/issues/30) about proxying requests but it has not seen any action in a while.

While developing you can define a [proxy in package.json](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) but that does not do anything for production builds.

If you just need something quick and easy you could go with [local-web-server](https://github.com/lwsjs/local-web-server). You can even run it directly with `npx`

```
npm run build
npx local-web-server \
  --port 8080 \
  --directory build \
  --spa index.html \
  --rewrite '/api/(.*) -> http://localhost:4242/api/$1'
```